# Using UNIQUE() within Window Partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to return all non-null values within a specific partition of a window function with BigQuery. The ideal state would be to be able to do something like:

```
UNIQUE(columnName) OVER (Partition by col1, col2)
```

However, when I try that, the error states:

```
Error: Unrecognized is not currently supported as an analytic function.
```

Thus, I'm assuming that something this direct isn't currently possible.

Does anyone have an elegant way of making this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Outside of Mikhail's answer, you may be interested in following the [feature request for IGNORE NULLS with analytic and aggregate functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=587).

Comment: if answer below does not address your question  - please clarify what is expected output - simple example will be great!

Comment: So I completely understand the `GROUP BY` options, but these are very resource intensive when the tables get large, which mine are. Window functions work extremely well in the scenario I have. Thanks @ElliottBrossard for the link; I'll be following that feature request.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways - depends on what exactly input and (most importantly) output you expect
How about

```
SELECT col1, col2, GROUP_CONCAT(UNIQUE(STRING(columnName))) AS values
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

if columnName is already of STRING type  - you can omit use of STRING() function